# Why does the browser add padding around svg elements and how can I prevent it?

Tags: html, svg

I'm trying to use SVG to make a graphic like this:

[image]

Here, the purple boxes are spans with a white right border, and there are 12 in each column. Setting the width to 8.333% (which is 100 / 12) makes this work out.

For various reasons (such as printing), I'm trying to do this instead with `svg` elements, like so:

```
<div class="svg-test">
  <svg>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"></rect>
  </svg>
  ....10 more of the same      
  <svg>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"></rect>
  </svg>
</div>
```

with simple styling:

```
.svg-test 
{
  width: 400px;
}

.svg-test svg 
{
   height: 20px;
   width: 8.333333%;
   fill: #7a5c8e;
}
```

(and see here: https://jsfiddle.net/un8L04ec)

There is no padding or margin on any of these elements (and the browser tools confirm this) and yet all browsers render this markup like so:

[image]

The browser is adding some unwanted padding, which causes my boxes, whose widths total 100%, and thus should fit on one line, to wrap to the next line. Why would this be, and what can I do to prevent it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your SVGs are inline elements and inline elements are sensitive to whitespace in your code. Remove the white space in your code and the gaps go away.

```css
.svg-test {
  width: 400px;
}

.svg-test svg {
  height: 20px;
  width: 8.333333%;
  fill: #7a5c8e;
}
```

```html
<div class="svg-test">
  <svg>
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"></rect>
      </svg><svg>
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"></rect>
      </svg><svg>
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"></rect>
      </svg><svg>
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"></rect>
      </svg><svg>
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"></rect>
      </svg><svg>
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"></rect>
      </svg><svg>
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"></rect>
      </svg><svg>
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"></rect>
      </svg><svg>
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"></rect>
      </svg><svg>
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"></rect>
      </svg><svg>
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"></rect>
      </svg><svg>
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"></rect>
      </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Very helpful, thanks. However, these are being generated in a loop in a templating engine, such that it would be very tricky to guarantee that there was no whitespace, because I'm not actually emitting the text directly. I thought changing the display to `inline-block` would accomplish the same thing, but it doesn't seem to work. Finally, I still see a thin white line between the blocks, and that ghost padding might still ruin things for some applications. So I'm still a bit stuck.

Comment: @JoshuaFrank What about floating them left?

Comment: It looks like `display:flex`, with suitable options does solve the problem. Accepting answer for getting me very close.

Answer (score 0):

This is a default behavior of web browsers. please read https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/.

If you want to remove spaces between elements just add negative margin to them

```css
.svg-test 
{
  width: 400px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.svg-test svg {
  height: 20px;
  width: 8.333333%;
  fill: #7a5c8e;
  margin-left: -4px;
  margin-bottom: -4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="svg-test">
      <svg>
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"></rect>
      </svg>
      <svg>
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"></rect>
      </svg>
      <svg>
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"></rect>
      </svg>
      <svg>
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"></rect>
      </svg>
      <svg>
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"></rect>
      </svg>
      <svg>
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"></rect>
      </svg>
      <svg>
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"></rect>
      </svg>
      <svg>
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"></rect>
      </svg>
      <svg>
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"></rect>
      </svg>
      <svg>
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"></rect>
      </svg>
      <svg>
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"></rect>
      </svg>
      <svg>
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"></rect>
      </svg>
    </div>
```